# SetUnhandledExceptionFilter dose not wok properly in QThread

Tags: c++, windows, qt, exception, qthread

i call SetUnhandledExceptionFilter to set a exception-handle function in main() function of my QApplication, it does not trigger the handler function when my QThread crashes, but the same code that crashes can trigger the hanler funciton in main thread(UI thread). i'm really wondering why that happens?

Comment: this mean that exception handled before it reach callback, set by SetUnhandledExceptionFilter

Comment: but i did not  manually handle the exception,  it was handled by the system?  if i want to capture the exception in the thread and record it in the dmp file, what should i do?

Comment: not by the windows built-in modules, but probably by Qt code (can not say this exactly, because never use Qt, but no another variants). you can use [VEH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/vectored-exception-handling) for capture and log exceptions

Comment: VEH really works, although it will creat needless dmp files in QT framework, thanks! i tried another method of __try/__exception, it also works in QThread.